Kotlin: [Internal Error] java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: FILE_HASHING_STRATEGY
After upgrading IntelliJ IDEA from 2023.1.1 to 2024.1.3, I compiled a Maven project and got:
Kotlin: [Internal Error] java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: FILE_HASHING_STRATEGY
Complete stacktrace:
Kotlin: [Internal Error] java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: FILE_HASHING_STRATEGY
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.jps.targets.KotlinJvmModuleBuildTarget.updateChunkMappings(KotlinJvmModuleBuildTarget.kt:362)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.jps.build.KotlinBuilder.doBuild(KotlinBuilder.kt:463)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.jps.build.KotlinBuilder.build(KotlinBuilder.kt:299)
        at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:1609)
        at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1238)
        at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1389)
        at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:1203)
        at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:971)
        at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:527)
        at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:236)
        at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:135)
        at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:387)
        at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:212)
        at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:211)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)


First, you can use the Bundled version for the Kotlin compiler version.

Second, make sure that you have set correct version for the Target JVM version in your Kotlin Compiler settings. It should be the same version as in your pom.xml, like below:
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>

After I set those values correctly and restarted IntelliJ IDEA, my issue was resolved. Additionally, I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1.4 (Community Edition).

The problem can happen because IntelliJ IDEA uses Kotlin compiler version 1.6.0 by default. How to resolve:

Open settings;
Type in the search "kotlin compiler";
Set compiler version to 2.0.0;



Quick fix:
In the POM, I upgraded Java and Kotlin versions to:
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.9.24</kotlin.version>

(I assume I could have raised Java to a more recent version, but for the moment by corporate rules we must not go beyond JDK 17)

It looks as resolved via the following ticket:
KTIJ-29067 JPS: "NoSuchFieldError: FILE_HASHING_STRATEGY" caused by Maven project with 1.6
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-29067/JPS-NoSuchFieldError-FILEHASHINGSTRATEGY-caused-by-Maven-project-with-1.6

Project Settings => Facets => Use Project settings

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
